# Android Studio: "can not find decleration to go to"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I want to see source code of Gradle Tasks or methods. When I hold the Control key and click on the for example, `dependencies`, Android Studio shows me this error:

[image]

```
Cannot find declaration to go to
```

How can solve this problem?

Comment: try delete
.gradle
.idea
build
and folder from your project and reopen the project. and it will solve this issue.